# Codeigniter transactions with other non-db functions?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, transactions

is it possible to have a code like this?

```
// send email with email+password and create user (in one transaction)
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->User_model->add_user($user_object);
MY_Controller::send_mail($to, $subject, $mail_data);
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

It's codeigniter. I use active record class. Static function send_mail returns FALSE if failed, add_user returns FALSE if affected rows == 0...

I would like to have that non-db function (send_mail) in transaction and if it fails - do rollback.

I know there is something like `$this->db->trans_status()` and I can run transactions manualy, but I think about this much more nicer code block. **Is it even possible to have non-db functions in transaction this way?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can only do a manual rollback in case that `send_mail()` fails:

```
if ( ! MY_Controller::send_mail($to, $subject, $mail_data))
{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
```

Comment: Okay, I'll use it this way. But I thought it's possible... maybe I seen it with PDO (when we work on a project). And it worked... So, thank you, Narf!